# Trying to receive text via a socket

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to do a simple test off sending data to a socket where the server program then sends data back. I can send the data but don't seem to receive data back. I have checked the server program and I receive the data successfully and used wireshark to watch the traffic and the server program is sending data but my client isn't able to get the data.
I have hidden the ip address and port for obvious reasons.

```
    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {

        //TODO Need filshills public ip address
        echoSocket = new Socket("xxxxxx",xx);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to host.");

    }
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream())), true);

    //PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    pw.flush();

    pw.print("MS01,test,06,000027,01\r\n");
    pw.close();
    try{
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    String check = stdIn.readLine();
    check = check + "";
    //BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
         stdIn.close();
    }
    }catch ( Exception e)
    {
        String neil = e.getMessage();
        neil = neil + "";
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();

    echoSocket.close();
```

Comment: are you sure the server sent /r/n at the end?

Comment: Have you tried doing .flush() AFTER the .close() call?

Comment: yes no joy the stdIn is always null. it was giving me a force close error when i called the BufferedReader line to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not close `PrintWriter`, according to [getOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29), `close` will close socket:

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.